# how to download the jquery-ui file of Uncompressed source , i download the file always jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, download

how to download a jquery-ui file without **.min.js

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grab the 1.8.5 uncompressed version here: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.js

Or, on the [jQuery UI Homepage](http://jqueryui.com/) look on the right under **Developer Links** for [Latest dev bundle](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/files/jquery-ui-1.8.5.zip) (1.8.5), you'll find `jquery-ui.js` under the `ui` folder.